# generating java code from wsdl using jaxb that requires pkcs11 auth over https

Tags: soap, https, jaxb, wsdl, pkcs#11

I have a problem generating wsdl2java code from an endpoint that requires pkcs11 (smatcard) authentication. I have configures jaxb maven plugin like this :

```
   <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.13.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                <generatePackage>hello.wsdl</generatePackage>
                <schemas>
                    <schema>
                        <url>https://mysecuredwsdl.com?wsdl</url>
                    </schema>
                </schemas>
            </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

When i execute the generate task i get this error :

> [ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [].
>   com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; IOException thrown when processing "https://...?wsdl". Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target.
>       at com.sun.tools.xjc.ErrorReceiver.error(ErrorReceiver.java:94)
>       at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForest.parse(DOMForest.java:402)
>       at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForest.parse(DOMForest.java:274)
>       at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.buildDOMForest(ModelLoader.java:324)
>       at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.loadWSDL(ModelLoader.java:391)
>       at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:170)
>       at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:119)
>       at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.loadModel(XJC22Mojo.java:50)
>       at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.doExecute(XJC22Mojo.java:40)
>       at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.doExecute(XJC22Mojo.java:28)
>       at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.doExecute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:505)
>       at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.execute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:328)
>       at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
>       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
>       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
>       at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
>       at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
>   Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>       at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)
>       at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302)
>       at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296)
>       at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509)
>       at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
>       at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
>       at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
>       at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1513)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:647)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:148)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:805)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
>       at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
>       at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForest.parse(DOMForest.java:394)
>       ... 37 more
>   Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>       at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387)
>       at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
>       at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
>       at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
>       at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
>       at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
>       at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491)
>       ... 57 more
>   Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
>       at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
>       at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
>       at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
>       at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)

Now, i tried running the maven task using this parameters :

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=NONE -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS11 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=1111 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=NONE -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=PKCS11 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=1111 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreProvider=SunPKCS11 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreProvider=SunPKCS11
```

I got this error :

> com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; IOException thrown when processing "https://...?wsdl". Exception: java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext). 
>   Caused by: java.security.NoSuchProviderException: no such provider: SunPKCS11

So after that i tried to eliminate the keyStoreProvider and trustedStoreProvider properties :

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=NONE -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS11 -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=1111 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=NONE -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=PKCS11 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=1111
```

I got this error :

> [ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [].
>   com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; IOException thrown when processing "https://....?wsdl". Exception: java.net.SocketException: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext).
>       at com.sun.tools.xjc.ErrorReceiver.error(ErrorReceiver.java:94)
>       at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForest.parse(DOMForest.java:402)
>       at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.internalizer.DOMForest.parse(DOMForest.java:274)
>       at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.buildDOMForest(ModelLoader.java:324)
>       at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.loadWSDL(ModelLoader.java:391)
>       at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:170)
>       at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:119)
>       at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.loadModel(XJC22Mojo.java:50)
>       at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.doExecute(XJC22Mojo.java:40)
>       at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.doExecute(XJC22Mojo.java:28)
>       at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.doExecute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:505)
>       at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.execute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:328)
>
> PKCS11 KeyStore not available

I made a connection using apache http to this secured webservice. So i know that i can connect to it. I used this test code :

```
@Test
public void testCertificate() throws CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException, IOException, KeyManagementException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
    // Trust own CA and all self-signed certs
    KeyStore ks = getKeystore();
    ks.load(null, "1111".toCharArray());
    SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(ks,new TrustSelfSignedStrategy()).loadKeyMaterial(ks,"1111".toCharArray())
            .build();
    // Allow TLSv1 protocol only
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(
            sslcontext,
            new String[]{"TLSv1"},
            null,
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());
    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf)
            .build();
    try {

        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://...?wsdl");

        System.out.println("Executing request " + httpget.getRequestLine());

        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        try {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
            EntityUtils.consume(entity);
        } finally {
            response.close();
        }
    } finally {
        httpclient.close();
    }
}




    private KeyStore getKeystore(){
    String pin = "1111";
    char[] pin_arr = pin.toCharArray();
    String pkcs11config = "name = SmartCard\n"  + "library = c:/windows/system32/eTPKCS11.dll";
    byte[] pkcs11configBytes = pkcs11config.getBytes();
    ByteArrayInputStream configStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pkcs11configBytes);
    Provider pkcs11Provider = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(configStream);
    Security.addProvider(pkcs11Provider);

    KeyStore smartCardKeyStore = null;
    try {
        smartCardKeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS11");
    } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return smartCardKeyStore;
}
```

I have no other ideas. Maybe jaxb2 is not the best option. I tried using Apache CXF but the problem remains. I cannot authenticate.

Thx.

Comment: Do not compile online resources. Make local copies and configure catalog files to rewrite absolut URL.

Comment: With apache cxf this is what I've done. I saved the wsdl file locally and i did a wsdl2java. It seems jaxb  maven plugin cannot generate from local resources.

Comment: Nonsense. :) Of course it can.

Comment: Do you have a config for the plugin that can do wsdl2java from local wsdl files?

Comment: I found the solution to generate from local files.